# UIViewController view is chopping off

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller

I am new to iOS and ObjectiveC and trying to add a viewcontroller to my existing program. It is showing partly in iPhone 6..any suggestions to reset the view to display all?

Comment: Too little information about your problem, no screenshots, no code. No one can help you with this description.

Comment: Can't upload picture because of my rookie status on StackOverflow...Let me elaborate the problem better...can't see anything laid on the right hand side...including bar buttons, can see only half textView box...when rotate right (into landscape mode) then I can see button etc. but can see only top half of textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it's due to [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html).  You either need to setup constraints so your elements appear correctly, or select a specific size class and arrange the elements for that size class.

Comment: Thanks Ron!! Do I need setup constraints for navigation bars, buttons, and all other elements in the viewcontroller? or can I apply globally for all?

Comment: You should setup constraints for all the things in all the views.